# How to convert an ArrayList to a strongly typed generic list without using a foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, list, arraylist, generic-list

See the code sample below.  I need the `ArrayList` to be a generic List.  I don't want to use `foreach`.

```
ArrayList arrayList = GetArrayListOfInts();  
List<int> intList = new List<int>();  

//Can this foreach be condensed into one line?  
foreach (int number in arrayList)  
{  
    intList.Add(number);  
}  
return intList;
```

Comment: In case you are not sure that arrayList contains only expected types, filter them arrayList.OfType<MyClass>().ToList().   See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7845009/52277

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Try the following

```
var list = arrayList.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

This will only work though using the C# 3.5 compiler because it takes advantage of certain extension methods defined in the 3.5 framework.

Comment: While I've certainly used this before myself, I'm considering boxing/unboxing. Won't that retract from performance? Sometimes I find that pretty code is at the expense of speed and resources...

Comment: That's just a consequence of putting it in an ArrayList in the first place.  Just casting every member back to an int is pretty much the best you can do performance-wise.

Comment: @mquander, true, true... I just realized the for-loop in the OP's post does just that as well. =)

Comment: Somehow, I missed Cast<> in the System.Linq namespace.  I wrote my own extension method that I can remove now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is inefficient (it makes an intermediate array unnecessarily) but is concise and will work on .NET 2.0:

```
List<int> newList = new List<int>(arrayList.ToArray(typeof(int)));
```

Comment: I did `arrayList.ToArray(typeof(int)) as int[]` and then it worked thanks! +1

Answer (score 4):

How about using an extension method?

From http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-arraylist-list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert ArrayList to List.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this ArrayList arrayList)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>(arrayList.Count);
        foreach (T instance in arrayList)
        {
            list.Add(instance);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In .Net standard 2 using `Cast<T>` is better way:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.AddRange(new[]{"Micheal", "Jack", "Sarah"});
List<int> list = al.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

> `Cast` and `ToList` are extension methods in the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class.