# Why does one line error but the other one doesn't?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

My question is simple really but hours of Google doesn't produce the answer to my (apparently) unique situation.
The problem is use of an unassigned variable in the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SimpleBasicCompiler
{
    class Lines : System.Collections.IEnumerable
    {
        // Variables
        private ArrayList<string> lines;

        // Constructor
        public Lines()
        {
            lines = new ArrayList();
        }

        public void Add(string line)
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        // Iterator
        public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length(); i++)
            {
                yield return lines[i];
            }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
               XFormMain.SetStatus(line); // this line errors
               System.Console.Write(line); // this line dosn't
            }
        }

    } // End Class Lines
} // End namespace
```

my question is why?
I can't change the declaration or it voids the iterator syntax
i even tried the following

```
public void Print()
    {
        string lineB = "";
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
           lineB = line; // now this line errors
           XFormMain.SetStatus(lineb); // and this line doesn't
           System.Console.Write(line); // this line doesn't in either situation
        }
    }
```

i guess if I knew WHY one line works and one line didn't i could figure it out but..... any ideas?

Comment: What does the error exactly say?

Comment: And why are you using ArrayList?

Comment: You should return lines.GetEnumerator() instead of yielding items.

Comment: How are we supposed to know why it doesn't work? We are humans, not incomplete code snippet compilers. Post the error message.

Comment: Is there even such a class as `ArrayList<string>` in .NET?

Comment: @MarkByers: Good point. Not in the .NET libraries.

Comment: The exact error is "use of unassigned local variable 'line'"

Comment: @Everett: Are you sure it's the first error? There appear to be other errors in your code. Earlier errors can sometimes make spurious errors appear later, so anything after the first error should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: The error is obviously because of the enumerator is for a screwed up ArrayList<T> implementation

Comment: I think you should be using List<string>, not ArrayList<string>. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390965/arraylist-to-listt

Comment: First let me say that I apologize for not being a code guru but alas i'm just a student. Second return lines.GetEnumerator(); errors on me and tells me "cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration" Third i'm trying to do what my teacher asked me to do but he is a person who gives us examples in python explains them in java and asks us to write them in c#. Fourth i expected more than bashing from "professionals" if it were obvious to me i wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: To those who were not sarcastic and slightly obnoxious I appreciate the help! as for why i'm using an arraylist is because I was told to by my teacher.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has serious issues (not compilable, even without the `Print` method). No `ArrayList<T>` class exists. That should be `List<string>` I think. I have never seen an appropriate use of `ArrayList` yet.

The error you get is probably because `ArrayList` is untyped (which is what makes it a terrible list implementation), yet you are asking it for strings. The compiler knows that it may contain arbitrary objects, and it stops you from assuming that it has only strings.

I suppose the reason the second line doesn't error is because the compiler stopped when it hit the first error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (string line in lines.ToArray(typeof(string)))         
{
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles:

```
    class Lines : System.Collections.IEnumerable {
        // Variables
        private ArrayList lines;

        // Constructor
        public Lines() {
            lines = new ArrayList();
        }

        public void Add(string line) {
            lines.Add(line);
        }

        // Iterator
        public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++) {
                yield return lines[i];
            }
        }

        public void Print() {
            string lineB = "";
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
               lineB = line;
//               XFormMain.SetStatus(lineb);
               System.Console.Write(line); 
            }
        }
    }
```

There were several problems:

ArrayList is in System.Collections, not System.Collections.Generic

ArrayList is not a Generic, so `ArrayList<string>` is incorrect

ArrayList.add doesn't exist

ArrayList.length() doesn't exist

Here is a suggestion that may help. Code a little bit first, and see that it compiles. Start with just empty class declarations. If your class descends from another, add that next, and stub out any methods required by the base class or interface to get it to compile. Add the internals of the methods one at a time and compile as you finish each one. Compiling often like this will avoid weird issues caused by multiple errors in your code. It will also stop you early from heading down an incorrect track, like using ArrayList as a generic.