# VB.NET ArrayList to List(Of T) typed copy/conversion

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have a 3rd party method that returns an old-style ArrayList, and I want to convert it into a typed ArrayList(Of MyType).

```
Dim udc As ArrayList = ThirdPartyClass.GetValues()
Dim udcT AS List(Of MyType) = ??
```

I have made a simple loop, but there must be a better way:

```
Dim udcT As New List(Of MyType)
While udc.GetEnumerator.MoveNext
    Dim e As MyType = DirectCast(udc.GetEnumerator.Current, MyType)
    udcT.Add(e)
End While
```

Comment: While you may find prettier code, you will always know exactly what this code is doing. And it's probably what the CLR is doing underneath anyway.

Comment: @Bill I thought the CLR could optimize, maybe using internal variables I have no access to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Dim StronglyTypedList = OriginalArrayList.Cast(Of MyType)().ToList()
' requires `Imports System.Linq`
```

Comment: Cast is not a member of ArrayList

Comment: @vulkanino: Yes, it's an *extension method*. As I said, it requires System.Linq namespace to be included in the current compilation unit.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the "requires" part. Anyhow I don't want to include Linq only for that cast. :)

Comment: @vul Unless you're not referencing System.Core assembly in the first place, not "including" Linq is unlikely to be justifiable. It's just a name for a bunch of C# features. It's a simple C# method and it's not something that has a big overhead. You could also call the method directly with `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast(Of MyType)(OriginalArrayList))`

Comment: I am unsure why there is an extra () at ().ToList(), I didn't need that.  But I did need to include System.Linq and that fixed my issue.  I had cloned a class and was wondering why the clone failed at that cast for the new cloned class.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate.
Have a look at this SO-Thread: [In .Net, how do you convert an ArrayList to a strongly typed generic list without using a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786268/in-net-how-do-you-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-strongly-typed-generic-list-without)

In VB.Net with Framework < 3.5:

```
Dim arrayOfMyType() As MyType = DirectCast(al.ToArray(GetType(MyType)), MyType())
Dim strongTypeList As New List(Of MyType)(arrayOfMyType)
```

Comment: this solution is concise but creates a temporary "standard" array.

Comment: @Vulkanino: you could write it in one line but without extension methods you must create an array implicitely with toArray or fill the list in a loop. Hence its always expensive and may not be used repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Public Class Utility

    Public Shared Function ToTypedList(Of C As {ICollection(Of T), New}, T)(ByVal list As ArrayList) As C

        Dim typedList As New C
        For Each element As T In list
            typedList.Add(element)
        Next

        Return typedList
    End Function

End Class
```

If would work for any Collection object.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out something about both the DirectCast and System.Linq.Cast (which are the same thing in the latest .NET at least.) These may not work if the object type in the array is defined by the user class, and is not easily convertable into  object types that .NET recognizes. I do not know why this is the case, but it seems to be the problem in the software for which I am developing, and so for these we have been forced to use the inelegant loop solution.