# Convert 'ArrayList' to 'List<string>' (or 'List<T>') using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I want to convert an `ArrayList` to a `List<string>` using LINQ. I tried `ToList()` but that approach is not working:

```
ArrayList resultsObjects = new ArrayList();
List<string> results = resultsObjects.ToList<string>();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In .Net, how do you convert an ArrayList to a strongly typed generic list without using a foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786268/in-net-how-do-you-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-strongly-typed-generic-list-withou)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your code *actually* shows a `List<ArrayList>` rather than a single `ArrayList`. If you're really got just one `ArrayList`, you'd probably want:

```
ArrayList resultObjects = ...;
List<string> results = resultObjects.Cast<string>()
                                    .ToList();
```

The `Cast` call is required because `ArrayList` is weakly typed - it only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. Almost all the LINQ operators in LINQ to Objects are based on `IEnumerable<T>`.

That's assuming the values within the `ArrayList` really are strings. If they're not, you'll need to give us more information about how you want each item to be converted to a string.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your first line was meant to be `ArrayList resultsObjects = new ArrayList();`.

If the objects inside the `ArrayList` are of a specific type, you can use the [`Cast<Type>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method:

```
List<string> results = resultsObjects.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

If there are arbitrary objects in `ArrayList` which you want to *convert* to strings, you can use this:

```
List<string> results = resultsObjects.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString())
                                                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LINQ's OfType<> method, depending on whether you want to raise an exception if one of the items in your arrayList is not castable to the desired type. If your arrayList has objects in it that aren't strings, OfType() will ignore them.

```
var oldSchoolArrayList = new ArrayList() { "Me", "You", 1.37m };
var strings = oldSchoolArrayList.OfType<string>().ToList();
foreach (var s in strings)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
Me
You
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `ArrayList` elements to `object[]` array using `ArrayList.ToArray()` method.

```
 List<ArrayList> resultsObjects = new List<ArrayList>();
 resultsObjects.Add(new ArrayList() { 10, "BB", 20 });
 resultsObjects.Add(new ArrayList() { "PP", "QQ" });

 var list = (from arList in resultsObjects
                       from sr in arList.ToArray()
                        where sr is string 
                         select sr.ToString()).ToList();
```