# How to access functions within an object in an arraylist

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class called "Account" created by with a value (eg "new Account(amt)"). But how can I retrieve that amount from the object of Account class. I thought I could use "listOfAccounts[0].balance.ToString();" but when I try to use listOfAccounts[0] then the functions do not appear to be visible.

```
    private ArrayList listOfAccounts = new ArrayList();
    double amt = (double.Parse(txtAmount.Text));
    listOfAccounts.Add(new Account(amt));
    lblShowBalance.Text = listOfAccounts[0].balance.ToString();
```

My class is something like:

```
class Account
{
    private double balance;

    public double Balance { get; set; }

    public Account() { }

    public Account (double balance)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
```

Comment: Should probably be using `List<Account>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* cast the item:

```
 var acct = (Account)listOfAccounts[0];
 acct.balance.ToString();
```

**But don't do that!**

`ArrayList` in .Net has been obsolete since .Net 2.0 introduced generics almost 15 years ago. There's no good reason to **ever** use it new code. Instead, use a `List<T>`, which is the same thing, but strongly typed.

While I'm here: it's also not at all okay to use the `double` type for money. When dealing with money, you should always use `decimal` instead.

Put it all together like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public decimal Balance {get; set;}

    public Account() { }
    public Account(decimal balance)
    {
        this.Balance = balance;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfAccounts = new List<Account>();
        listOfAccounts.Add(new Account(133.1m));

        Console.WriteLine(listOfAccounts[0].Balance);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

And with a collection initializer for fun:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfAccounts = new List<Account> {new Account(133.1m)};
        Console.WriteLine(listOfAccounts[0].Balance);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast elements to `Account` then **public** members are accessible :

```
private ArrayList listOfAccounts = new ArrayList();
double amt = (double.Parse(txtAmount.Text));
listOfAccounts.Add(new Account(amt));
lblShowBalance.Text = ((Account)listOfAccounts[0]).Balance.ToString();
```

and your class should look like this to get the balance value:

```
class Account
{
  private double balance;

  public double Balance { get { return balance; } }

  public Account() { }

  public Account (double balance)
  {
      this.balance = balance;
  }
}
```

For casting all of elements to strongly types look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786268/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-strongly-typed-generic-list-without-using-a-for)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an `ArrayList` stores Objects. You want to refer to it as an `Account` rather than `Object` (as in the base object type from which other objects inherit). 
There's a few problems with the code, but to answer your question, you can cast that object back into an Account type:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList listOfAccounts = new ArrayList();
        double amt = double.Parse("133.1");
        listOfAccounts.Add(new Account(amt));
        Console.WriteLine(((Account)listOfAccounts[0]).balance.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public double balance;
    public Account() { }
    public Account(double balance)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Ideally however, you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` at all: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8

If you replace the above with `List<Account>` everything becomes much better:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Account> listOfAccounts = new List<Account>();
        double amt = double.Parse("133.1");
        listOfAccounts.Add(new Account(amt));
        foreach(Account account in listOfAccounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(account.balance.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```